# Android: Listener for change in text to speech settings

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

Hello working with text to speech.

I am targeting API 16 so I launch this intent to start TTS settings on the device

```
public Intent launchTTSSettings(){
        Intent TTSSettings = new Intent();
        TTSSettings.setAction("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS"); 
        TTSSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        return TTSSettings;
    }
```

My app goes in the background.

I change some TTS settings

My app comes back into foreground, I notice that my app still uses the old TTS settings unless i close and open again the app again.

I want to way to listen to any changes to TTS settings maybe a broadcast receiver, but I could not find anything related to that.

So is there any way i can gracefully respond to changes in TTS settings?

I was thinking i could destroy my TTS instance and re-make it but the root of the problem is how do I know if a setting was actually changed

Thanks for reading

Comment: Added an answer. Please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came with a solution which is not really great but it seems to work as it abides by the changes

Please note I have not introduced a progress dialog and wait until onInit called but here is the logic

So here i launch my text to speech settings intent and set a flag to true

```
startActivity(mTextToSpeechHelper.launchTTSSettings());
mTTSSettingsHasChanged = true;
```

Then in on resume

```
      @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if(mTTSSettingsHasChanged){
            mTTSSettingsHasChanged = false;
            mTextToSpeechHelper.destroy();
            mTextToSpeechHelper = null;
            mTextToSpeechHelper = new TextToSpeechHelper();
            }
        }
```

note that destroy does this because my TTS stuff is in a helper class

```
  public void destroy(){
        if(mTextToSpeech != null){
            mTextToSpeech.stop();
            mTextToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

What is not good is that the user could go into settings but not change anything which would resort in the old instance being destroyed and a new one made for no productive reason